# Passing Ext Store data to php

Tags: php, javascript, json, extjs

I have an EditorGridPanel on my page.
My goal is to pass the updated data to PHP via POST method.
Though I want it to happen only after clicking the Save Button.
I know I can achieve it by converting the data to an array and sending it like a form, but is there a better way?
I've tried using JsonWriter, but it sends requests every time I update data in the grid.

So what is the best way to do it?

Comment: If you show some code for your EditorGrid I can help you with the code for sending it to the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JasonWriter is a good way to save your records, what you are missing is `autoSave: false,` in store definition.

```
autoSave : Boolean
Defaults to true causing the store to automatically save records to the server 
when a record is modified (ie: becomes 'dirty'). Specify false to manually 
call save to send all modifiedRecords to the server.
Note: each CRUD action will be sent as a separate request.
```

Basicly you should write your own method for saving records. Most of availble examples focusing on sending just modified records `var modified = Store.getModifiedRecords ();` followed by extracting and encoding, your need is to send all records will simplify that operation.

Sorry that I do not have on-line example handy, I base and I would recommend to look in "ExtJS in Action" by Jesus Garcia where is nice chapter about CRUD via EditGridPanel

Comment: Is there a way to send all the data, not only the updated one? and does it work with POST?

Comment: Thanks, I finally gave it up and used simple ajax request and javascript for getting the store and parsing it to string

Answer (score -3):

Use jquery. On save button click event create your json and use $.post function.

Comment: thank you, but i don't have a clue about jquery, and don't have time for learning it right now

Comment: OK. I don't want to push you to anything. BUT I had the same opinion about a half a year ago. Since I learned basics of jquery(one afternoon job) I saved 80% of my time on each project(I mean javascript, html, css fiddeling time). Their motto is "write less do more" and thats true.

Comment: -1, why are you advising him to use jquery to send data from an ExtJS data store to the server?

Comment: Don't know Ext JS. I like jQuery. That's why i advised it. Is it impossible to integrate these two together? But you're right I probably shouldn't have. sorry